# How to study high-dimensional topology?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I really would like to learn about the foundations of high-dimensional topology, the study of manifolds of dimensions 5 or greater.  I learned the algebraic topology, but much of focus in what I learned in topology, such as geometric topology, has been low-dimensional manifolds.  I concluded that I am intensely more interested about high-dimensional manifolds than low-dimensional manifolds; unfortunately, it seems that there are no introductory textbooks or monographs about high-dimensional manifolds.

Where should I begin with?  What topics should I study that are core of high-dimensional topology?  I have a feeling that surgery and cobordism theories are important, but I am not sure.  Should I instead trying to read past research articles than specific textbooks?

Comment: Milnor's little book "Lectures on the $h$-cobordism theorem" is, like most Milnor books, quite beautiful.

Comment: I see!  What topics beside cobordism are central to high-dimensional topology, as there seems no book about it

Comment: The key word to look up is "Surgery Theory". Ranicki's "Algebraic and Geometric Surgery" is a pretty accessible introduction.

Answer (score 2):

The only (I am quite sure) textbook for higher-dimensional manifold topology is

*Antoni A. Kosinski*, Differential manifolds, Pure and Applied Mathematics, 138. Boston, MA: Academic Press. xvi, 248 p. (1993). [ZBL0767.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0767.57001).

This edition is expensive, but the book was also republished in paperback form by Dover (2007) which is affordable.

The book even has a fair number of exercises. It starts very gently (at the same level and pace as most textbooks on differential topology) but eventually gets to advanced topics such as the h-cobordism theorem and surgery theory. Of course, as Lee Mosher suggested, you cannot go wrong with Milnor's "h-cobordism" book, but it was not written as a textbook.